# Rectangles Performance

Tags: java, performance, libgdx

I'm creating a simple 2d platformer game using libgdx and I'm using Rectangle class. So which of these options is better?

1. Create one HUGE rectangle
2. Create a lot of small rectangles

[image]

Comment: thats a pretty inaccurate question

Comment: Why? I just need to know Is it better to have one big rectangle or lots of small.

Comment: My guess would be one big rectangle as you are working with one object instead of several, but have you tried benchmarking?

Comment: yes, but for what? rendering? the model? what are the requirements? basically all i can say without knowing anything is that you should always reduce data and therefore use one huge rectangle

Comment: A question: Are you sure you need a `Rectangle`? If the `Rectangle` should only be the floor you can't fall through, a height check might be enough. So you wuld only have a "line"

Comment: Are you talking about physics or graphics performance? In either case, a single rectangle uses less CPU. For graphics, the many rectangles use less memory if the texture is tileable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a memory standpoint, one rectangle should be more compact than several, so I'd start with one. Also with one rectangle you avoid the trap-on-border problem that multiple rectangles pose.